# A question of implementing a generalized quicksort in C

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

I was trying to create a method simulating the qsort provided by the library. However, I noticed a bug appears causing the segmentation fault in the line `void* pivot = calloc(1,width);`. Could any one analyze it for me?

```
void MyQuickSort(void* ary,int nlem, unsigned int width,int (* pfCompare) (const void *, const void *)){
    if(nlem<=1){
        return;
    }else{
        int left = (int) ary;
        int right = (int) ary+(nlem-1)*width;
        void* pivot = calloc(1,width);
        memmove((void *)pivot,ary,width);
        left = NULLL;
        //NULLL is a macro constant here

        while(left!=right){
            // as (void*)left is NULL, check (void*)right
            if(left == NULLL){
                if(pfCompare(pivot,(void*)right)<=0){
                right -= width;
                //remain the current ele
                }else if(pfCompare(pivot,(void*)right)>0){
                    memmove((void *)left,(void *)right,width);
                    right = NULLL;
                    //move the ele in right to left
                }
            }else{
                if(pfCompare(pivot,(void*)left)>=0){
                left += width;
                //remain the current ele
                }else if(pfCompare(pivot,(void*)left)<0){
                    memmove((void *)right,(void *)left,width);
                    left = NULLL;
                    //move the ele in left to right
            }
        }
        memmove((void *)left,pivot,width);

        MyQuickSort(ary,(left-width-(int)ary)/width,width,pfCompare);
        MyQuickSort(right+width,nlem-((left-width-(int)ary)/width),width,pfCompare);

        free(pivot);

    }
}
}
```

the analysis of the code and the error; fixing the bug if possible; some explanation

Comment: Welcome @totoa It would be great if you could provide the code you use to invoke that function, so we can try to reproduce exactly what you see.

Comment: why are you doing this `int left = (int) ary;`.? Forcing a void pointer to be an int? For a start it wont fit on a 64 bit machine

Comment: What's a `NULLL`?

Comment: Aside: `void* pivot = calloc(1,width); memmove((void *)pivot,ary,width);` maybe simplified, if you want to skip allocation failure checking,  with `void* pivot = memcpy(malloc(width), ary, width);`

Comment: For the int part, I was trying to implement the offset of the address so to read the next element. NULLL basically is a flag here checking if the element has been check or not.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, errors start from the first line:

1. `int left = (int) ary;` - converts pointer to int and stores it in int. It makes no sense
2. `int right = (int) ary+(nlem-1)*width;` same, it is even hard to say what you have in mind
3. `memmove((void *)pivot,ary,width);` do not cast without the reason. p1 and p2 would be avoided if not explicit casts. **Do not use casts to silence the warnings**
4. `left = NULLL;` what is `NULLL` and if it is `NULL` why do you assign it to `int` variable?

etc. etc.

Remove all casts, **read the warnings** and rethink what you have written.

> I noticed a bug appears causing the segmentation fault in the line
> void* pivot = calloc(1,width);

This line does not invoke undefined behaviour, thus it is very unlikely to cause the segfault

Answer (score 0):

Thank u, I've just modified my previous one and now it works.
I shouldn't arbitrarily use the int cast for the `ary` to do the offset which may easily cause an error. Instead, I replace it by using some `char*` pointer which is more compatible.

Here is part of my revised version:

```c
 char *left = (char *)ary;
        char *right = (char *)ary + (nlem - 1) * width;
        void *pivot = calloc(1, width);
        memmove(pivot, ary, width);
        int leftF = NUL;
        int rightF = NUL;
```

The `NUL` here is defined as a macro constant simulating a flag for condition checking. Of course, other corresponding parts are corrected also.

Comment: why not use NULL, thats the classic flag indicator for a pointer

Comment: totoa, Rather than only _describe_ `NUL`, post its code definition.

Comment: totoa, Why the unnecessary cast in `char *left = (char *)ary;`?